# Cardinality of Cartesian product of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was unable to find a proof (let alone a short one) for the proposition that
$$|A\times A| = |A|\text{ for any infinite set }A.$$

The function from right to left is trivial, but I cannot find one from left to right.

Would be happy for help.

Comment: In the infinite case, this is $not$ a trivial result (as far as I know). [Enderton](https://books.google.com.mx/books/about/Elements_of_Set_Theory.html?id=JlR-Ehk35XkC&redir_esc=y) has a proof that I found relatively easy to understand.

Comment: The statement that for any infinite set $A$, the cardinality of $A$ and $A\times A$ is the same, is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice (this is Tarski’s Theorem); so it is not surprising that you are having some difficulty proving it. You’ll need the Axiom of Choice to establish it in generality.

Comment: Allright then, is it easier to show just for 'R' (real numbers vectors)

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}$, there are some ad hoc arguments you can make. For example, Cantor proved that $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ has the same cardinality as $[0,1]$ by "interweaving decimal representation" (map $(0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots,0.b_1b_2b_3\ldots)$ to $0.a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3\ldots$). And of course, $\mathbb{R}$ is bijectable with $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ with $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin In fact Cantor did *not* interweave decimal representations at all. He first showed the irrationals in $[0,1]$ satisfied it by interweaving continued fractions (which is cleaner, as they're unique) and then arguing about uncountable sets minus countable sets etc. I've read the original papers in German (while reading the biography by Dauben) and getting it for reals instead of just the irrationals was quite a struggle for Cantor, technically.

Comment: There are many questions on this site with answers to your question, both the general one and in the case of the reals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Helpful.

Comment: Sarcasm is equally helpful. I guess I was expecting you to use the search function on the website. Here, let me do that for you.

Comment: I've marked three duplicates on this. There *are* more. Especially if you're using ordinals and the well-ordering theorem to prove the general statement. The keywords here are "Gödel pairing". Good luck.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Thank you for the correction.